# I have an error when install ros-melodic-slam-gmapping

Tags: 18.04, ros

I want to install [ros-melodic-slam-gmapping](http://wiki.ros.org/gmapping) by command:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-slam-gmapping
```

but it doesn't work and error is

> E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-slam-gmapping

Could you help me?

Comment: Did you add `packages.ros.org` to your software sources list as per the [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)? And did you do `sudo apt update` afterwards?

Comment: Yes, i did. I decided the problem by downloading slam from git. (https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping and https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping) and move them in `~/catkin_ws/src/`. But thank you for you advice!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. The package maintainer status is unmaintained, so you should migrate to other solution.

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
sudo apt install libsdl-image1.2-dev

cd ~/catkin_ws/src/
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/openslam_gmapping
git clone https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation.git
git clone https://github.com/ros/geometry2.git
git clone https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation_msgs.git
cd ~/catkin_ws 
catkin_make  (or catkin build) -- Compiling will take a while but with ros melodic on a jetson agx and ubuntu 18.04 I didn't have issues.
```

(reference: https://www.programmersought.com/article/52912958276/)
Juan.